# make square image with blank image using carrierwave on rail4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, carrierwave, rmagick

I found Cropping and resize image using carrierwave,rmagick

```
def resize_and_crop(size)
  manipulate! do |image|
   if image[:width] < image[:height]
     remove = ((image[:height] - image[:width])/2).round
      image.shave("0x#{remove}")
    elsif image[:width] > image[:height]
      remove = ((image[:width] - image[:height])/2).round
     image.shave("#{remove}x0")
    end
    image.resize("#{size}x#{size}")
    image
  end
end
```

It's working so good.

But I wanna sqaure image on blank, height so long

ex) image  300 X 400
-> I Crop and resize

ex) image 300 X 800
-> I make blank square Image 800 X 800 and then resizing image like **instasize app**

any one know how I do?